# Instance of GenericArrayType interface

Tags: java, reflection

```
class ReflectionClass{
   public static void anyMethod(Type type){
      if(type instanceof GenericArrayType){
         // some code
      }
   } 
}
class Client{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      anyMethod(...);
   }
}
```

I'm trying to receive a "true" value in `if(type instanceof GenericArrayType)` statement.

So, what I should put as an argument into invocation of anyMethod method inside Client class?

From the Oracle Documentation about [GenericArrayType interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/GenericArrayType.html):

> GenericArrayType represents an array type whose component type is either a parameterized type or a type variable.

But, I also know that I can't create arrays of parameterized types from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays)

Thus, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use reflection on any method, field, etc that's a generic array type.

For example, `List.toArray(T[]) -> T[]`

```
List.class.getMethod("toArray", Object[].class).getGenericReturnType();
```

Or declare a generic array yourself, and reflect on it

```
public List<String>[] array;

MyClass.class.getField("array").getGenericType()
```